# filezilla Connection timed out

Tags: filezilla, connection-timeout

This might seem like a duplicate question but it is not. I tried to go through similar questions but I couldn't find a fix for my problem. Here is my problem:

I need to set up an ftp connection on company servers.
I can easily connect to ftp server from fileZilla on my PC but when I try it over one of the server machines to the file server all I see is the following:

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "*****@***.***.***.**" **
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to ***.***.***.**...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "*****@***.***.***.**" **
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I googled the "Connection timed out"
error and I realized that the first place to check is firewall or router setting. these are outsourced to another company and they say that the issue is solved and it should work fine. I don't know where to look at.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? i am having same issue

Comment: facing same issue, but no answer here!

Answer (score 1):

I've had lots of issues with Filezilla. You may try another software first to see if Filezilla itself is the issue.

If you're on Windows, I highly suggest the open source project WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). For Mac, Cyberduck (https://cyberduck.io/?l=en) is solid (and free), though you may prefer Transmit.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem after upgrading Filezilla. I downgraded it to a previous version and it worked like charm. I came across this ticket thread and it was absolutely helpful : [Filezilla Support Ticket](https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/9995)

Answer (score 0):

Check your security group rules. You need a security group rule that allows inbound traffic from your public IP address(Google: What is my ip?) on the proper port.
Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
In the navigation pane, choose Instances, and then select your instance.
In the Description tab, next to Security groups, choose view rules to display the list of rules that are in effect.
For Linux instances: Verify that there is a rule that allows traffic from your computer(public ip) to port 22 (SSH).
For Windows instances: Verify that there is a rule that allows traffic from your computer(public ip) to port 3389 (RDP).

Also take a look at [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-application-server.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout) for more details

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set up an ftp connection on company servers. I can easily connect to ftp server from fileZilla on my PC but when I try it over one of the server machines to the file server all I see is the following:
>
> `<failure to connect code>`

Please note that public IP and internel IPs will be a different address; such as `123.456.675.574` for the public but internal to the server network it will be something more like `192.168.10.574` .

This is why you can easily connect from your PC because it uses the public IP address but from the internal IP network of the company servers that address will not be valid, and the internal one would need to be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, 200 is just an example, just increase it and try.
Edit --> Settings --> Connection --> Timeout in seconds = 200